# Client IP is not preserved using Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

In our organization there is requirement when we access application through Application gateway public ip address it is routing to backend pool configured ip(where application is configured) and showing up application.
But all our traffic routing through F5 firewall , in firewall logs we can see APP gateway public ip only whenever the user hits URL.

Requirement is we need to see client IP address where end user is trying to access to restrict from firewall end.

I tried to add a rewrite rule on the Gateway to force X-FORWARDED-FOR header with {var_client_ip} value.

But still not working can anyone gone through this type of requirement and can suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

To see the client Ip address where end user is trying to access, please check the below:

In my environment I created azure application gateway a with backend service as app service to check client ip go to advance tool in your backend service.

***Go to app service -> Advanced tool -> Go -> Environment -> HTTP header -> Client IP***

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can find the client IP address like below.

[image]

Because the Application gateway is a proxy, you are unable to preserve the client IP. To set the rewrite rule in azure application gateway use this client IP like below

[image]

You can use header rewrite from the X-Forwarded-For header to only keep the IP address alternatively you can make use of **`add_x_forwarded_for_proxy`** and try to modify the request and response headers.

To know more in detail please ***refer*** this link:

[Rewrite HTTP headers and URL with Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#remove-port-information-from-the-x-forwarded-for-header)